# чтение данных в hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

Что должен получать метод `(EntityModel) template.get("EntityModel", id)`?  В моем случае id - это просто primaryKey, а EntityModel это имя таблицы.

```
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
        public EntityModel getEntMod(Long id){

           EntityModel entityModel = (EntityModel) template.get("EntityModel", id);

            return entityModel;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы откроете [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html) по HibernateTemplate, то там это прямо написано:

```
public Object get(String entityName,
                  Serializable id)
           throws DataAccessException
```

> Return the persistent instance of the given entity class with the
>   given identifier, or null if not found. This method is a thin wrapper
>   around Session.get(String, java.io.Serializable) for convenience. For
>   an explanation of the exact semantics of this method, please do refer
>   to the Hibernate API documentation in the first instance.
>
> Parameters:
>
> entityName - the name of the persistent entity
>
> id - the identifier of the persistent instance

Если вы не указываете параметр `name` в аннотации / XML, то entityName такое же как название вашего класса.

```
@Entity(name="MyEntityName")
```

Я бы посоветовал вам оставить HibernateTemplate - никто им реально не пользуется. И использовать Hibernate напрямую. Примеров таких в сети будет гораздо больше.